# Trying to combine two MapDatasets to become one MapDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, concatenation, tensorflow-datasets, data-augmentation

I am trying to combine these two mapdatasets into one. In other words, I am trying to expand my dataset.

```
ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: (load_aug(tf.image.resize(x, size)), y))
ds1 = ds1.map(lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(x, size), y))
```

ds is an augmented version of a dataset an ds1 is a regular unaugmented dataset. The shape of the images in both datasets are the same.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @Kris I am try to combine both ds and ds1 to become one mapdataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip` or `concatenate` to combine both MapDatasets:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 4)
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 8) 

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds, ds1))
# or 
train_dataset = ds.concatenate(ds1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Btw what if I wanted to mix them together as opposed to concatenating at the end?

Comment: Just zip together with `train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds, ds1))` and then use `train_dataset.map(your_mix_up_function)` to do whatever you want.